# JButton Customization Issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, custom-component, paintcomponent

I need some help with customizing JButton.

I am using following extended method to do so ... I need to add backgound color to the button and also i need to place two different text at two location in the button(Top Left & Center)

My code is not able to support both the scenarios(Color and Text Position). Either I am able to have the text located or I am able to get a BG color.
In the current code I am getting BG color but text in not appearing

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor( color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(47, 33));

        if (isHeader) {
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
            g.drawChars(date.toCharArray(), 0, date.length(), 13, 20);
            //setBackground(color);

        } else {
            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 9));
            g.drawChars(date.toCharArray(), 0, date.length(), 3, 11);

            g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
            g.drawChars(hours.toCharArray(), 0, hours.length(), 18, 20);

        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        g.finalize();
    }
```

Comment: Crosspost http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2263469&tstart=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it looks like you *are* drawing the text, but you're drawing it in the same color as the background, so you won't be able to see it. Black text on a black background is just black.

You need a different color for the text and the background. Something like;

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(backgroundColor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(47, 33));

    g.setColor(textColor); //set the text color before drawing the text
    if (isHeader) {
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        g.drawChars(date.toCharArray(), 0, date.length(), 13, 20);
    } else {
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 9));
        g.drawChars(date.toCharArray(), 0, date.length(), 3, 11);

        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        g.drawChars(hours.toCharArray(), 0, hours.length(), 18, 20);
    }
    super.paintComponent(g);
    setContentAreaFilled(false);
    g.finalize();
}
```

These seems to be a couple of other funnies in your code. Why don't you use `setBackground()` and why do you call `super.paintComponent()` twice?

**Edit:**  Also, why are you setting the component's size in the paint method? That seems wrong. And why are you calling `finalize()` on the `Graphics` object?

Comment: HI Qwerky Thanks so much .. I got the issue and its working fine now for me.  I am working on Swing for the first time ... have been a J2EE guy ... so kindly excuse my funny mistakes :) Hi StanislavL ... Thanks to you as well for helping me :) ...

Comment: -1 for repeating the utterly unclean code again: never-ever (as in _really_ never, not even when hell freezes over) change component state in paintXX.